# How to Generating Dynamic ID in JQuery without using For Loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are 7 Question in form with number 1.1 to 1.4 and 2.1 to 2.3, having Radio as answer(ID: #radio_1.1 and #radio_1.2) and textarea for comments(ID: #textarea_1.1, #textarea_1.2).

Questions are dependent on one another like question 1.4 answer if selected "yes" in radio, then will disable textbox of Question 2.2. Also, need to achieve this functionality during click as well as on load.

Following is way i am generating question id for now in JQuery/Javascript:

```
for(var tabNumber=1;tabNumber<=2;tabNumber++) {
    var questions=0;
    if(tabNumber==1) questions=4;
    if(tabNumber==2) questions=3;
    for(var decimalNumber=1;decimalNumber<=questions;decimalNumber++){
       disableit(tabNumber+"\\."+decimalNumber,value); //This generate id of comment box like #textarea_1.1, #textarea_1.2 and radio also like #radio_1.1 and #radio_1.1 and even few classs like .Class_1.1 and .Class_1.2
    }
}
```

in disableit we have functionality like:

```
$(".Class_"+number).addClass("yahooeffect");
$("#textarea_"+number).attr('disabled', true);
```

Is there any alternative in JQuery/Javascript which helps to remove for loop and do above operations in another simpler way? Any Regular expression which can help me like .Class_[1.1-1.9] etc, so that i can applu things in just one or two statements?

**Update**

Each Question is in one line. Like (1.1 - Do you want bird? YES/NO Comment) (1.2 - Do you want Doggy? Yes/No Comment). Each of these 4 in seperate div like div for 1.1 and div for question and div for radio and div for comment. So ID's are separated as explained in question. Questions have mixed dependency

Answer (score 0):

Try [`uniqueId`](https://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/)

**Example:**

```
$(selector).uniqueId();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="checked">1</div>
<div class="checked">2</div>
<div class="checked">3</div>
<div class="checked">4</div>
<div class="checked">5</div>
<div class="checked">6</div>
<div class="checked">7</div>
<div class="checked">8</div>
<div class="checked">9</div>
<div class="checked">10</div>
<div class="checked">11</div>
<div class="checked">12</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".checked").uniqueId();
});
```

Result:

```
<div class="checked" id="ui-id-1">1</div>
<div class="checked" id="ui-id-2">2</div>
<div class="checked" id="ui-id-3">3</div>
<div class="checked" id="ui-id-4">4</div>
<div class="checked" id="ui-id-5">5</div>
<div class="checked" id="ui-id-6">6</div>
<div class="checked" id="ui-id-7">7</div>
<div class="checked" id="ui-id-8">8</div>
<div class="checked" id="ui-id-9">9</div>
<div class="checked" id="ui-id-10">10</div>
<div class="checked" id="ui-id-11">11</div>
<div class="checked" id="ui-id-12">12</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/693/

> Many widgets need to generate unique ids for elements. `.uniqueId()` will check if the element has an id, and if not, it will generate one and set it on the element. It is safe to call `.uniqueId()` on an element without checking if it already has an id. If/when the widget needs to clean up after itself, the `.removeUniqueId()` method will remove the id from the element if it was added by `.uniqueId()` and leave the id alone if it was not. `.removeUniqueId()` is able to be smart about this because the generated ids have a prefix of "ui-id-".

Answer (score 0):

Have elements have a common class. For example, `class="question"`. Then you can target all of them using `$(".question")`. If they have unique IDs, use ID to target them individually: `id="question-1.1"` and `$("#question-1.1")`. If you can't use IDs, assign two classes: `class="question question-1.1"`, then you can use `$(".question")` for all or `$(".question-1.1")` for one.

Comment: Each Question is in one line. Like (1.1 - Do you want bird? YES/NO Comment) (1.2 - Do you want Animal? Yes/No Comment). Each of these 4 in seperate div like div for 1.1 and div for question and div for radio and div for comment. So ID's are separated as explained in question. As question have mixed dependency on each other so could not declare one lass for all. Individual ID target will increase code unnecessarily suppose 30 question more added.

Comment: You already have individual classes (`Class_1.1` or similar); ID matching is faster than class matching, so if `Class_1.1` is unique on page, converting to ID would be preferable.

Comment: In Radio Divs,unable to use classes. As In radios, i need to verify if one is selected disable other, so i need to play on ID's only. So this will not work for me.

Comment: I am sorry, you narrative is confusing. Please consider making a jsfiddle to demonstrate your HTML structure, and describe in detail what you would want to happen.